# Trigonometric Identities, are they injective or well-defined?

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry

Proving trignometric indentities is quite simple, when you know certain properties of $e^{ix}$. Therefore identites such as $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$ and $\sin(x+y)=...$ by simply using Eulers Identity and comparing Real Parts to each other and Imaginary Part to each other!

My question: What guarantees me to say that if the Imaginary/Real Part of $z$ is equal to Imaginary/Real Part of $w$ then they are actually eqaul. To be more precise, is it defined as a function ? Then this function has to be injective. A quick example plotting the function $x^2$ on $2$and$-2$ will give me the number 4 but this doesnt tell me that $-2=2$ since x^2 is not injective. Thanks

Comment: Equality of $x+yi$ and $r+si$ is defined as being true if and only if $x=r$ and $y=s.$ Think of coordinates and when two coordinate vectors are equal.

Comment: yes i believe that the coordinates is explicit and well-defined, therefore they have to be equal

Answer (score 1):

You ask

> What guarantees me to say that if the Imaginary/Real Part of $z$ is
> equal to Imaginary/Real Part of $w$ then they are actually equal?

That is essentially the definition of complex numbers as pairs of real numbers. It has nothing to do with trigonometric identities, or the injectivity of any functions of real or complex variables.

Comment: since the pairs of real numbers is ecplicit and well-defined there is no room for misunderstanding. I beleive thats the explanation

Comment: @Maths Complex numbers are often defined as ordered pairs of real numbers. So the notation $a+bi$ is just a convenient shorthand for $(a,b)$. And since ordered pairs are *ordered*, $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: @Joe exactly thanks, thats what i also found out and concluded. Thats actually an axiom/definition, but i beleive my question is still valid, and lots people assume it is given.

Comment: @Maths Yes, it's just a definition. There are other ways to define complex numbers, but there's nothing wrong with this approach, and it's the simplest. However you decide to construct them, it is always true that $a + bi = c + di$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: exactly since i have derived that the complex numbers are equal so have to be their real and imaginary parts.